# cp -nv - how can I only print copied files without the "skipping ..." messages?

Tags: linux, cp

I'm often using `cp -nv`. The newest version also prints messages like
`skipped some/file.txt`
for all files already existing on the target between listing the files that are actually copied. In this vast output, it's hard to find the relevant part. And I'm using the `v` because I want to see a list of the copied files.

I could not find a suitable parameter in the man page.
Of course, I could filter this using `| egrep -v '^skipped '` but having to do this every time is cumbersome, that's why I'm looking for a more elegant solution.